# access site.email variable in _data yaml file

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I have `_data/navigation.yml` file that looks like

```yaml
main:
  - title: email
    url: mailto:hardcoded@email.sop
```

The problem is that Idk how to reuse `email` variable from the `_config.yml` in the `_data/navigation.yml` file.

Here is part of my `_configl.yml`

```yaml
title: title configured
email: configured@email.sop
```

I've tried to adjust the `_data/navigation.yml` file like below

```yaml
main:
  - title: email
    url: mailto:{{ site.email }}
```

but the navigation link is generated like `mailto:{{%20site.email%20}}`

I suppose it should be `mailto:configured@email.sop` as any other `.md` page output has.

(this is Jekyll 4.2.0 site is using the
[minimal-mistake](https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/)
theme)

Comment: In order for files to be processed with Liquid, they must contain (possibly empty) [Front Matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/03-front-matter/). I am not sure whether this works with files in `_data` but you can try to put two consecutive `---` lines on the top of the file to enable Liquid processing.

Comment: @flyx Thanks for the hint. I've tried to add two `---`  lines to the beginning of `navigation.yml` but it did not help. Even more - top level menu line has gone from the web page.